# Why doesn't this program ( for product of two matrices ) work?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to write a program which calculates the product of two matrices `A` and `B`.

```
function [ C ] = Untitled (A,B);
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
B = [1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1];
[m,n] = size(A);
[k,l] = size(B);

if (n~=k)
    C = [];
    disp( 'AB Tulo ei ole määritelty');
    return
    
end
C = zeros(m,1);
for i = 0:m
    for j = 0:l
        for p = 0:n
            flag = 1;
            C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,p) * B(p,j);
        end
    end
end
end
```

The program does not work. Matlab is telling me `Error in Untitled (line 18)`

```
C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,p) * B(p,j);
```

What does this error message mean?.  Moreover, the product C is simply a `[0,0,0]` vector, and on top of that, running this script drops Matlab into debug mode.

Comment: Array index in MatLab starts from 1, your loops start from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essential to start the indices of the tables at `1`, and not at `0` as in algorithms. Moreover, the loops are only on `i` and `j`, no need to include `p` as in the mathematical formula.

The problems in your code are on both levels.

Your code with some corrections:

```
 function [ C ] = Untitled (A,B);

       A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
       B = [1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1];
       [m,n] = size(A);
       [k,l] = size(B);
       
       if (n~=k)

           C = [];
           disp( 'AB Tulo ei ole määritelty');
           return
           
       end
   
       C = zeros(m,m);
       for i = 1:m
           for j = 1:l
               C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,:)*B(:,j);
           end
       end

 end
```

[Documentation on `mtimes`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html)